# I want to display two map on same page. But map-canvas is displaying and map-canvas-2 is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display two map ion same page. The problem is "map-canvas" is displaying properly but map-canvas-2 is not displaying at all. What should I do now Please Help...

Here  is my HTML code...

```
            <div class="google-map wow fadeInDown col-sm-6" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="google-map wow fadeInDown col-sm-6" data-wow-duration="500ms">
                <div id="map-canvas-2"></div>
            </div>
```

Here is my JAVASCRIPT code

```
    function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.0285, 73.0586);
        var myLatLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(23.344101, 85.309563);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatLng,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            draggable: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        };

        var mapOptions2 = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: myLatLng2,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            draggable: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-2'), mapOptions2);


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
            title: 'Kharghar',
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng2,
            map: map2,
            icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
            title: 'Ranchi',
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);


        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-2'), mapOptions2);


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
            title: 'Kharghar',
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng2,
            map: map2,
            icon: 'img/location-icon.png',
            title: 'Ranchi',
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map2, marker2);
        });

        var styledMapOptions = {
            name: 'US Road Atlas'
        };

        var usRoadMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
        roadAtlasStyles, styledMapOptions);

        map.mapTypes.set('roadatlas', usRoadMapType);
        map.setMapTypeId('roadatlas');
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map2, marker2);
        });

        var styledMapOptions = {
            name: 'US Road Atlas'
        };

        var usRoadMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
         roadAtlasStyles, styledMapOptions);

        map.mapTypes.set('roadatlas', usRoadMapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('roadatlas');
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


        });
```

Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: seems you have duplicated  code .. remove the unuseful part  please

Comment: You need to make the entire call on a id, not call maps as different options. So, call #mapone #maptwo in their own calls and their own options and you're sorted. Example here: https://codepen.io/Marnoto/pen/VLjVZZ

Comment: I am supporting @scaisEdge comment. You should refactor your code by creating a function to display a map. It'll be easier for you and for us that way.